# Toast element stays visible all the time

Tags: toast, polymer

I try to write a web-component to create a simple login menu. it has paper-inputs for name and password and a button which fires a script to check the data.

the right data redirect to the next page while false credentials should open a toast element right above the button with an error message, siimilar to this one:

http://www.polymer-project.org/tools/designer/#6f21f8d26e14d614c9cb
Select the paper-toast-element in the tree-view and check the 'opened'-checkbox get get a vision what I try to do and please excuse the strange style.

The problem: 
I included this element in my main page, but the toast element is always visible right from the start. and it doesn't react to the button click if I move the toast away with css.

I don't wanna spam this page with my code, so I uploaded it here:
https://gist.github.com/Gemoron/6b8f41d1bb6ff522e23c

I appreciate any suggestion on how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 5):

- You cannot access the hidden shadow DOM of an element directly with jQuery's `$` function, nor with `document.querySelector`. Also jQuery is not needed anyway. Use [Polymer's automatic node finding utility](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#automatic-node-finding) instead: `this.$.paper_toast`.
- You can access the *paper-input* values with `this.$.name.inputValue`. But i would prefer to use data-binding instead: `<paper-input value={{name}}>`. Then you can access the input value in your JavaScript with `this.name`.
- The function to display the toast is `show()`.
- I'm unable to reproduce the issue that the toast is visible right after the page has loaded. On my computer the toast is initially hidden and displayed when i click on the button (Chrome 37, Polymer 0.3.3).

Answer (score 2):

In line 76 you try to use an "open()" method, which does not exist on paper-toast. It should be "show()". You can find paper-toasr API here: http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/paper-elements.html#paper-toast

Also, because the ids in shadow dom are encapsulated, you should be using the id selection mechanism from Polymer instead of jquery-style selector

```
this.$.paper_toast.show();
```

More on automatic node finding in Polymer: http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#automatic-node-finding

Here's jsbin (you might need to refresh as jsbin sometimes breaks with Polymer imports)
http://jsbin.com/fened/1/edit

Comment: Is the JsBin supposed to show the proper code? Seems like it's maybe not the right link.